# Each run of the same Hadoop SequenceFile creation routine creates a file with different crc. Is it ok?

Tags: hadoop, crc, sequencefile

I have a simple code which creates Hadoop's Sequence file. Each the code is ran it leaves in working dir two files:

```
   mySequenceFile.txt
   .mySequenceFile.txt.crc
```

After each run the sizes of both files remain the same. But the crc file contents become different!

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing, but **expected** behaviour.
According to [SequenceFile standart](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile), each sequencefile has a **sync-block**, its length is 16 bytes. The sync-block repeats after each record in block-compressed sequencefiles, and after some records or one very long record in uncompressed or record-compressed sequencefiles.
The thing is, that the **sync-block** is some sort of **random value**. It is written in the header, so this is how the reader recognizes it. It stays **same within one sequencefile**, but it can (and actually is) **different from one sequencefile to another**.
So the files are logically same, but binary different. CRC is binary shecksum, so its different between two files too.
I haven`t found any ways to manually set this sync-block. If someone gets the way, please write it here.